# Count # of word in a macro variable

Tags: sas

I need to import multiple sheets from excel.

What I currently do is

```
%let _path = C:\;
%let _name = AOL.xlsx;
%let sheet_list  = AG ST;    

%macro Import;
   %local current_sheet;    
   %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&sheet_list.)); 
      %let current_sheet = %scan(&sheet_list., &i);    
      proc import out=SQ_&current_sheet. replace datafile="&path.\&_name.";
         sheet="&current_sheet.";
      run;
   %end;    
%mend Import;    
%Import;
```

But some other sheets' names contain blanks.

```
%let sheet_list = AG 11, AG 12, ST;
```

How can I adjust the above codes to cater this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the other parameter to the `COUNTW()` and `%SCAN()` functions so that you can set the delimiter. I wouldn't use comma as the delimiter since it would require macro quoting to use it in the function calls.  Use something like `|` that is an invalid character for a sheet name.

```
%let _path = C:\;
%let _name = AOL.xlsx;
%let sheet_list  = AG 11|AG 12|ST;

%macro Import;
%local i current_sheet;
%do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&sheet_list,|)); 
  %let current_sheet = %scan(&sheet_list., &i, |);
  proc import out=SQ_&current_sheet. replace datafile="&path.\&_name.";
     sheet="&current_sheet.";
  run;
%end;
%mend Import;

%Import;
```

Actually the spaces in the sheet name will also cause trouble when trying to use the sheet name as part of the SAS dataset name.  You could replace the spaces with underscores.

```
...
%local i current_sheet member_name;
...
  %let member_name = %sysfunc(translate(SQ_&current_sheet,_,%str( )));
  proc import out=&member_name replace datafile="&_path.\&_name.";
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If your list of worksheets is separated by commas then it's just a matter of counting either:

a) the commas+1 (for words)

b) the number of words directly with comma as the delimiter

```
%let sheet_list = AG 11, AG 12, ST;

data _null_;
*count with default delimiters for words;
VAR1=countw("&sheet_list");

*count with comma as the dlm;
VAR2=countw("&sheet_list",",");

*count number of commas;
VAR3=countc("&sheet_list",",");

call symputx('words_default',VAR1,'g');
call symputx('words_commas',VAR2,'g');
call symputx('count_commas',VAR3,'g');
run;

%put DEFAULT WORDS: &words_default;
%put COMMAS WORDS: &words_commas;
%put COMMAS COUNT: &count_commas + 1 for words;
```

Comment: Tom just mentioned a very good point.  So sticking with my solution (although his is completely viable) and a couple of lines shorter, in your %scan you'd need to quote the variables containing commas.  i.e. %scan(%bquote(&sheet_list),&i,%bquote(,));

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to count the words?  Seems like you just want something like

```
FOR word IN list DO import END
```

But SAS doesn't have that syntax in MACRO language so you have to write it your self. You also need to be able to specify the word delimiter.

```
24         %let _path = C:\;
25         %let _name = AOL.xlsx;
26         %let sheet_list  = AG ST;
27         
28         %macro Import(dlm=%str( ));
29            %local current_sheet i;
30            %let i = 1;
31            %let current_sheet = %scan(%superq(sheet_list),&i,&dlm);
32            %do %while(%superq(current_sheet) ne);
33               %put proc import out=SQ_&current_sheet. replace datafile="&_path.\&_name.";
34               %put sheet="&current_sheet.";
35               %put run;
36               %let i = %eval(&i + 1);
37               %let current_sheet = %scan(%superq(sheet_list),&i,&dlm);
38               %end;
39            %mend Import;
40         
41         %Import;
proc import out=SQ_AG replace datafile="C:\\AOL.xlsx"
sheet="AG"
run
proc import out=SQ_ST replace datafile="C:\\AOL.xlsx"
sheet="ST"
run
42         
43         %let sheet_list = AG 11, AG 12, ST;
44         %import(dlm=%str(,));
proc import out=SQ_AG 11 replace datafile="C:\\AOL.xlsx"
sheet="AG 11"
run
proc import out=SQ_AG 12 replace datafile="C:\\AOL.xlsx"
sheet="AG 12"
run
proc import out=SQ_ST replace datafile="C:\\AOL.xlsx"
sheet="ST"
run
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on  your codes,it could be worked after modification.

```
%let sheet_list =%str(AG 11, AG 12, ST);

%macro Import;
%local current_sheet;

%do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&sheet_list,%str(,))); 
    %let current_sheet = %scan(&sheet_list., &i,%str(,));

    proc import out=SQ_&current_sheet. replace datafile="&path.\&_name.";
         sheet="&current_sheet.";
    run;
%end;

%mend Import;

%Import;
```